# Display div border on top of another div

Tags: html, css, border, overlay

I have 2 divs, one partially overlaying another, like:

```
<div class="box1">
</div>
<div class="box2">
</div>
```

The classes:

```
.box1 {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 100;
 left: 100;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 border: 3px solid #4286f4;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background: blue;
}

.box1 {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 150;
 left: 150;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 border: 3px solid #4286f4;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background: red;
}
```

How to overlay the border of the first div on top of the second one?

Like this:
[image: Example]

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? Please check this fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/kawal/50uyh83c/1/

Comment: No, i want to display the border of the first div on top of the second.

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/kawal/50uyh83c/3 ?

Comment: Like this: https://imgbbb.com/image/L05xv7

Comment: Aah, you can try to add pseudo-class to achieve this. Check this https://jsfiddle.net/kawal/zqgace04/6/

Comment: That's it! Thanks.