# Display div border overlaying another div

Tags: css, border

I've tried the method showed here, but it aint worked out:

[StackOverflow: Display div border on top of another div [duplicate] (my own postage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59815853/display-div-border-on-top-of-another-div?noredirect=1#comment105777393_59815853)

I have 2 nested divs, and the above method isn't working for both divs.

Here is the code:

html:

```
<div className="App">
        <div class="box mainClass1" id="1">
          <div class="helperClass" />
        </div>
        <div class="box mainClass2" id="2">
          <div class="helperClass" />
        </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

.mainClass1 {
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  background: teal;
}
.mainClass2 {
  top: 150px;
  left: 150px;
  background: red;
}

.helperClass2 .helperClass {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #4286f4;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

note: helperClass2 should be added to the list of classes of parent (outer) div.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.box1 {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 100px;
 left: 100px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background: blue;
}

.box1:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 95px;
 height: 95px;
 position: absolute;
 border: 3px solid black;
 z-index: 3;

}

.box2 {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 150px;
 left: 150px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background: red;
 border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, but this dont solve my problem, i need the pattern of classes and divs up above